# NodeJS cookies don't work with sessions in Express 4

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express

I've updated my NodeJS application to Express 4.0 and now I can't set my own cookies in addition to the express-session cookie.  This problem only happens on the first request of any session, when the user reloads the page the custom cookies are there.

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(require('body-parser')());
app.use(require('method-override')());
app.use(require('cookie-parser')('cookie-secret'));
//app.use(session({ secret: 'secret', key: 'sid'})); //uncomment this to see the problem

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.cookie('testing', 'test'); //this isn't set if using 'app.use(session...)'
    res.send('This is a cookie test');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

To test:
1. Run the above code, the cookie "testing" is sent to the browser correct.
2. Then clear the cookies and uncomment the "app.use(session..." line.
3. Run the application and the only cookie is the "sid".  Where's "testing"?
4. Reload the page (without clearing cookies) and the "testing" cookie is there.

It's essential that all of my cookies are there on the first request.

Comment: did this work for you?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
var mw = {
  favicon: require('static-favicon'),
  logger: require('morgan'),
  bodyParser: require('body-parser'),
  cookieParser: require('cookie-parser'),
  session: require('express-session'),
  methodOverride: require('method-override')
};

var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(mw);
app.store = new MongoStore(...);


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if ('HEAD' === req.method || 'OPTIONS' === req.method) return next();
  var writeHead = res.writeHead;
  res.writeHead = function() {
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.session && req.session._csrfSecret);
    writeHead.apply(res, arguments);
  };
  next();
});

app.use(mw.session({
  key: 'yourCookieID',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 3600000 * 24 * 7
  },
  store: app.store
}));
```

Comment: Is this still the best way to deal with this issue? Looks like there is still no maintainer on that module. :(

Comment: I've moved on to JWT using jwt-simple (npm)

Answer (score 2):

In [`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#options) you are attempting to use the `key:` option which was replaced with `name:` option.  You will want to use the `genid:` option to set the `sid`, make sure it is unique(I suggest, uuid version 4).  The `express-session` package will also handle your cookie management.

```
// Session create
var hour = 3600000;

app.use(session({
    genid: function(req) {
          return uuid.v4(); // This comes from the node-uuid package
    },
    secret: 'secret key',
    cookie: { secure:  true,
              expires: new Date(Date.now() + hour),
              maxAge:  hour },
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
```

To access the session data:

```
req.session
```

To access the cookie data:

```
req.session.cookie
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem. See [this](https://github.com/expressjs/session/pull/16) GH issue.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize that. But that GH issue is very unclear as to what the resolution is.  Is there a resolution?

Comment: Waiting on amendments to the proposed commits I'd guess.